# JavaScript/Jquery - Copy table row inside a handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a function like this:

```
function isRowEmpty(){
        var emptyRow = true;
        var tableRow;
        $('#ProblemsGrid').delegate('td a', 'click', function() {
            tableRow = $(this).closest ('tr');
        });

        tableRow.find('textarea').each(function(index, element){
                var value = $(element).val();
                if(value != "") {emptyRow = false;}
            });
        return emptyRow;
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the table row that has the  that was clicked and check the  of that row to see if it's empty, then return true/false. I think the problem I got here has something to do with javascript closure. The var tableRow is not being changed in the outer function. I've been trying to figure out a workaround but no luck. I'm relatively new to JavaScript and Jquery.

Update: Here's how isRowEmpty() is used.

```
function deleteRow(){
        if (isRowEmpty()===true){
                $('#ProblemsGrid').delegate('td a', 'click', function() {
                 $(this).closest ('tr').remove();
                    }); 
        }
}
```

Here's part of my HTML:

```
<tr>
<td><textarea name='text' style='width: 98%; height:40px'>....</textarea></td>
<td><a href='#anchor' name='DeleteButton' onclick='deleteRow();'> 
<img src='../images/delete.gif'></img> </a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you show how are you using `isRowEmpty()`? and Your HTML

Comment: You are populating variables inside a handler and a callback which are executed asynchronous. But you treat your `isRowEmpty` as if it would be executed synchronous. You need to give some more information what you'd like to do.

Comment: I've just updated my question with how isRowEmpty is used and the related HTML. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Remove your delegate `$('#ProblemsGrid').delegate('td a', 'click', function() {` in deleteRow & isRowEmpty function, 2. In `onclick='deleteRow();'` pass this all the way to `isRowEmpty()` function

Comment: Satpal, I'm a bit unsure about your suggestion. What difference would it make? I'll give it a try. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should utilize the power of jQuery when you are using it. I tried to simplify your code:

```
$('.deleteRow').on('click', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var remove = true;
    tr.find('textarea').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
           remove = false;
        }
    });
    if (remove) {
        tr.remove();
    }
});
```

Just add a class `deleteRow` to your remove button/image and lose your inline event handler (`onclick='functionCall()`)

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ttHQ/2/)

It seems you're appending your rows dynamically, then your selector should look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {
  // ...
});
```

---

*By the way*. From the [`.delegate`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/#entry-longdesc) docs:

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the .on() method. In general, these are the equivalent templates for the two methods:

Comment: @manutd500 I've made mistake, one empty textarea would be enough to remove the table. Your `each` approach was right. I've edited it

Comment: I'm pretty sure your solution should work but somehow it doesn't when I try it. Do you think if it has something to do with the fact that I'm dynamically appending new rows to the table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteRow(){
        if (emptyRow){// isRowEmpty returning emptyRow
                $('#ProblemsGrid').delegate('td a', 'click', function() {
                 $(this).closest ('tr').remove();
                    }); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function isRowEmpty(el){
    var emptyRow = true;
    if(el.val() != "" && el.val() != "....")
        emptyRow = false;
    return emptyRow;
}

$(document).delegate('#ProblemsGrid td a', 'click', function() {
    if (isRowEmpty($(this).closest('tr').find('textarea'))){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/8bCfL/)